# Why reflection Mesh on a flat surface is zoomed with three.js ? How to correct it?

Tags: javascript, three.js

on this example http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Reflection.html we can observe that the sphere reflection is kept to the right scale compared to the flat square : in fact it seems like the reflection is zoomed.

I tried to modify the parameter of the mirrorCubeCamera object but the scale doesn't change.

I've seen the same phenomena in this official example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's not a "real" reflection. The technique used here is called [cube mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping) and is a very specific approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know if there's any way to have a real reflection ? I tried to use the mirror.js library like in this example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html but it seems like I can't use it as a material for a mesh...

Comment: Not that I've seen. It's not really trivial to implement. Take a look at something like this http://jcgt.org/published/0003/04/04/paper.pdf or google "screen space reflection". Consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I can recommend this book to cover some of these topics. It definitely has a chapter on flat reflections and i believe it covers cubemapping: https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Third/dp/1435458869